# What is the difference between parameters and body data in HTTP request in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

i am unable to provide request to the server in json format using parameters so please can anyone explain me about it? 
I sent this request from **Bodydata** extracting data from CSV:

```
POST data:
{
  "password":"login",
  "username":"568592"
}
```

but when i used **parameters** for extracting data from CSV:

```
POST data:
password=login&username=568592
```

How can i send json format request using parameters?

Answer (score 7):

There should be no difference given you properly pass your JSON via "Parameters" section.

1. If you want to use "Parameters" - just put your JSON payload into "Value" section of the 1st parameter like:

   [image: JMeter JSON via Parameters]
2. If you want to use "Body Data" - put your JSON Payload there (don't forget to remove everything from the "Parameters" section)

   [image: JMeter JSON as Body Data]
3. Don't forget to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of [`application/json`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Applications)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T for your answer.  In case of only one user it works fine but what about multiple users login fetching data from CSV ?